# Will a horse level up with you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, does your horse gain level with you or does it always stay at a fixed level?

If it gain levels, what are the benefits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, horses have straight levels. For example shadowmere is Lv50 while most horses you buy from a stable are level 4.